# Printing birthdates using maps and they end up as Octals

Tags: c++, iterator, octal

If I create a map for names and birthdays. When i enter birthdates that end in 0 it changes it the number to an octal. how do i print out the birthday ie `010525` == `4437` so when i call `it -> second` it will print `010525`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<string, int>birth;

    birth["Chicken"] = 010525;
    birth["Dragon"] = 010266;


    map<string, int>::iterator it;

    for(it = birth.begin() ; it != birth.end(); it++){
        cout << it -> first + " ";
        cout << it ->second << endl;

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chicken 4437
Dragon 4278
```

Comment: Use `std::string`?

Comment: store the birthdates as a string? Surely there's a way to not have to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this problem:

(1) The first way is to enter the birthday without the leading 0 as follow:

```
birth["Chicken"] = 10525;
birth["Dragon"] =  10266;
```

Then use `setfill()` and `setw()` to fill the leading 0.

Please note that the code that uses std:setw() and std::setfill() will compile only with new C++ compiler versions such as C++14 (or C++11)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<string, int>birth;

    birth["Chicken"] = 10525;
    birth["Dragon"] = 10266;


    map<string, int>::iterator it;

    for(it = birth.begin() ; it != birth.end(); it++){
        cout << it -> first + " ";
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(6) << it ->second << endl;

    }
}
```

(2) The second way is to store the birthday as string. This way you can enter the birthday with the leading 0.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<string, string>birth;

    birth["Chicken"] = "010525";
    birth["Dragon"] = "010266";


    map<string, string>::iterator it;

    for(it = birth.begin() ; it != birth.end(); it++){
        cout << it -> first + " ";
        cout << it ->second << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without setting it to a string? I tested this before posting but i wanted to find out if there's a way to keep it as an int and still use maps

Comment: @Drew, Yes, there is a way to do that without using the string. I just edited my answer. Please read the first method where you enter the birthday as integer without the leading 0 (zero).

Comment: `std::setw()` + `std::setfill()` for output.

Comment: Thanks to user "Evg" and "Drew" for the clarification and update. Please note that the code that uses std:setw() and std::setfill() will compile only with new C++ compiler versions such as C++14 (or C++11)

Answer (score 1):

You can go with using both as string in map like :

```
map<string, string>birth;
```

and rest keep as it is.